How to get a JButton to work properly in a static method
I am creating a GUI that asks the user to enter an account balance then click a confirm button. After the button is clicked, it is supposed to display the confirmed balance in the confirmed balance box. However, when I click the button, nothing happens. I tried using the "this" keyword in my addActionListener call, but I cant use it in a static method. How do I get the button to work?
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class Gui_container extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    private JFormattedTextField Balance_Field;
    private JTextField Confirm_Field;
    
    private static void create_GUI() {
        GridBagConstraints layout = new GridBagConstraints();
        JFrame New_Account = new JFrame("Account");
        New_Account.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        New_Account.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        
        JPanel Main_Panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        New_Account.setContentPane(Main_Panel);
        
        JLabel Balance_Label = new JLabel("Enter your Balance:");
        layout.gridx = 0;
        layout.gridy = 0;
        layout.insets = new Insets(10,10,10,10);
        Main_Panel.add(Balance_Label, layout);
        
        JFormattedTextField Balance_Field = new JFormattedTextField(NumberFormat.getNumberInstance());
        Balance_Field.setColumns(10);
        layout.gridx = 1;
        layout.gridy = 0;
        layout.insets = new Insets(10,10,10,10);
        Main_Panel.add(Balance_Field, layout);
        
        JLabel Confirm_Label = new JLabel("Confirmed Balance:");
        layout.gridx = 0;
        layout.gridy = 1;
        layout.insets = new Insets(10,10,10,10);
        Main_Panel.add(Confirm_Label, layout);
        
        JTextField Confirm_Field = new JTextField(10);
        layout.gridx = 1;
        layout.gridy = 1;
        layout.insets = new Insets(10,10,10,10);
        Main_Panel.add(Confirm_Field, layout);
        
        JButton Confirm = new JButton("Confirm");
        Confirm.addActionListener(null);
        layout.gridx = 0;
        layout.gridy = 2;
        layout.insets = new Insets(10,10,10,10);
        Main_Panel.add(Confirm, layout);
        
        New_Account.setContentPane(Main_Panel);
        
        New_Account.pack();
        New_Account.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        double balance;
        
        balance = ((Number) Balance_Field.getValue()).doubleValue();
        
        Confirm_Field.setText(Double.toString(balance));
        
        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                create_GUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
        


So far, I have tried using "this" and "null", and I have also tried changing main so that it calls the create_GUI() method differently, but nothing works so far.
